# Black Screen after deleting the record

Tags: laravel, flutter, api

I am using Laravel as the Backend API and Flutter for the Client. Category Add and Category Update features are working without any issue. However, when i delete a category, the category gets deleted from the database but returns the user to a black page. I am finding difficult to find the error.

**lib\screens\categories.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/models/category.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/widgets/category_edit.dart';

import 'package:demo_app/providers/category_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

// import '../widgets/category_add.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/widgets/category_add.dart';
// import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Categories extends StatefulWidget {
  const Categories({super.key});

  @override
  State<Categories> createState() => _CategoriesState();

}

class _CategoriesState extends State<Categories> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<CategoryProvider>(context);
    List<Category> categories = provider.categories;

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Categories'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: categories.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Category category = categories[index];
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(category.name),
                      trailing: 
                          Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  showModalBottomSheet(
                                    isScrollControlled: true,
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (context) {
                                      return CategoryEdit(category, provider.updateCategory); 
                                      });
                                },                         
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                            onPressed: () => showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) {
                                return AlertDialog(
                                  title: const Text('confirmation'),
                                  content: const Text('Are you sure you want to delete?'),
                                  actions: [
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () => deleteCategory(provider.deleteCategory, category),
                                      child: const Text('Confirm')
                                    ),
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                      child: const Text('Cancel')
                                    ),
                                  ]
                                );
                              }
                              ),                              
                          ),
                            ],
                          ),
                    );
                  },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
                isScrollControlled: true,
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return CategoryAdd(provider.addCategory);
                });
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add)
      ),
    );
  }

  Future deleteCategory(Function callback, Category category) async{
    await callback(category);
    if (!mounted) return;
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

}
```

**lib\providers\category_provider.dart**

```
  import 'package:demo_app/models/category.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/providers/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/services/api.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CategoryProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  List<Category> categories = [];
  late ApiService apiService;
  late AuthProvider authProvider;

  CategoryProvider(this.authProvider){
    apiService = ApiService(authProvider.token);

    init();
  }

  Future init() async{
    categories = await apiService.fetchCategories();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> addCategory(String name) async{
    try{
      Category addedCategory = await apiService.addCategory(name);
      categories.add(addedCategory);

      notifyListeners();
    } catch(e){
      await authProvider.logOut();
      // ignore: avoid_print
      // print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateCategory(Category category) async{
    try{
      Category updatedCategory = await apiService.updateCategory(category);
      int index = categories.indexOf(category);
      categories[index] = updatedCategory;

      notifyListeners();
    } catch(e){
      await authProvider.logOut();
    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteCategory(Category category) async{
    try{
      await apiService.deleteCategory(category.id);
      categories.remove(category);      
      notifyListeners();
    } catch(e){
      await authProvider.logOut();
    }
  } 

}
```

**lib\services\api.dart**

```
  // import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:demo_app/models/category.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/models/transaction.dart';

// import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class ApiService{

  late String token;

  ApiService(this.token);

  final String baseUrl = 'http://flutter-api.test/api/';

  Future<List<Category>> fetchCategories() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('${baseUrl}categories'),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
        },
      );

    List categories = jsonDecode(response.body);

    return categories.map((category) => Category.fromJson(category)).toList();
  }

  Future <Category> addCategory(String name) async {

    String uri = '${baseUrl}categories';

    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
        },
        body: jsonEncode({'name': name}));
        
        if(response.statusCode != 201){
          throw Exception('Error happened on create');
        }

    return Category.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }
  
  Future <Category> updateCategory(Category category) async {

    // String uri = '${baseUrl}categories/$category.id';
    String uri = '${baseUrl}categories/${category.id}';

    http.Response response = await http.put(Uri.parse(uri),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
        },
        body: jsonEncode({'name': category.name}));
        
        if(response.statusCode != 200){
          throw Exception('Error happened on update');
        }

    return Category.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }

  Future<void> deleteCategory(id) async {

    String uri = '${baseUrl}categories/$id';    

    http.Response response = await http.delete(Uri.parse(uri),
    headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
        },
      );
    
 
    if(response.statusCode != 204){
          // // ignore: avoid_print
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(response.statusCode);
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(response.body.toString());
      throw Exception('Error happened on delete');
    }

  }

  Future<List<Transaction>> fetchTransactions() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('${baseUrl}transactions'),
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
      },
    );

    List transactions = jsonDecode(response.body);

    return transactions.map((transaction) => Transaction.fromJson(transaction)).toList();
  }

  Future<Transaction> addTransaction(String amount, String category, String description, String date) async {
    String uri = '${baseUrl}transactions';

    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          'amount': amount,
          'category_id': category,
          'description': description,
          'transaction_date': date
        }));

    if (response.statusCode != 201) {
      throw Exception('Error happened on create');
    }

    return Transaction.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }

  Future<Transaction> updateTransaction(Transaction transaction) async {
    String uri = '${baseUrl}transactions/${transaction.id}';

    http.Response response = await http.put(Uri.parse(uri),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          'amount': transaction.amount,
          'category_id': transaction.categoryId,
          'description': transaction.description,
          'transaction_date': transaction.transactionDate
        }));

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Error happened on update');
    }

    return Transaction.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }

  Future<void> deleteTransaction(id) async {
    String uri = '${baseUrl}transactions/$id';
    http.Response response = await http.delete(
      Uri.parse(uri),
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode != 204) {
      throw Exception('Error happened on delete');
    }
  }

  Future<String> register(String name, String email, String password, String passwordConfirm, String deviceName) async {
    // ignore: prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings
    String uri = baseUrl + 'auth/register';
    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri),
      headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
        },
      body: jsonEncode({
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'password_confirmation': passwordConfirm,
        'device_name': deviceName
      })
    );
    if(response.statusCode == 422){
      Map<String, dynamic> body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      Map<String, dynamic> errors = body['errors'];
      String errorMessage = '';
      errors.forEach((key, value){
        value.forEach((element){
          errorMessage += element + '\n';
        });
      });

      throw Exception(errorMessage);
    }
    // if(response.statusCode == 422){
    //   throw Exception('Error happened on registration');
    // }

    return response.body;
  }

  Future<String> login(String email, String password, String deviceName) async {
    // ignore: prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings
    String uri = baseUrl + 'auth/login';
    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri),
      headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',          
        },
      body: jsonEncode({
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'device_name': deviceName
      })
    );
    if(response.statusCode == 422){
      Map<String, dynamic> body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      Map<String, dynamic> errors = body['errors'];
      String errorMessage = '';
      errors.forEach((key, value){
        value.forEach((element){
          errorMessage += element + '\n';
        });
      });

      throw Exception(errorMessage);
    }
    // if(response.statusCode == 422){
    //   throw Exception('Error happened on registration');
    // }

    return response.body;
  }
 

}
```

**lib\providers\auth_provider.dart**

```
import 'package:demo_app/services/api.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  bool isAuthenticated = false;
  late String token;
  late ApiService apiService;

  AuthProvider() {
    init();
  }

 Future<void> init() async {
  token = await getToken();
  if (token.isNotEmpty) {
    isAuthenticated = true;
  }
  apiService = ApiService(token);
  notifyListeners();
}

  Future<void> register(String name, String email, String password, String passwordConfirm, String deviceName) async{
  token = await apiService.register(name, email, password, passwordConfirm, deviceName);
  isAuthenticated = true;
  setToken();
  notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> logIn(String email, String password, String deviceName) async{
  token = await apiService.login(email, password, deviceName);
  isAuthenticated = true;
  setToken();    
  notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> logOut() async{
  token = '';
  isAuthenticated = false;
  setToken();  
  notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> setToken() async{
    final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.setString('token', token);
  }

  Future<String> getToken() async {
    final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = pref.getString("token") ?? "";
    return token;
}



}
```

**lib\main.dart**

```
import 'package:demo_app/providers/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/providers/transaction_provider.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/screens/register.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/screens/categories.dart';
// import 'package:demo_app/screens/transactions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:demo_app/providers/category_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AuthProvider(),
      child: Consumer<AuthProvider>(builder: (context, authProvider, child){
        return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<CategoryProvider>(
          create: (context) => CategoryProvider(authProvider)),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<TransactionProvider>(
          create: (context) => TransactionProvider(authProvider)),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(
      title:'Welcome to Flutter',      
      routes: {
        '/': (context) {
          final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
          if(authProvider.isAuthenticated){
          return const Home();
          }else{
            return const Login();
          }
        },
        '/login': (context) => const Login(),
        '/register': (context) => const Register(),
        '/categories': (context) => const Categories(),
      }));      
    }
    )
  );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**lib\screens\categories.dart**

```
  Future deleteCategory(Function callback, Category category, BuildContext context) async{
    await callback(category);
    if (!mounted) return;
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

Solved the issue

I changed the headers in the **lib\services\api.dart** too

**lib\services\api.dart**

looks like this

```
// import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:demo_app/models/category.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/models/transaction.dart';

// import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class ApiService{

  late String token;

  ApiService(this.token);

  final String baseUrl = 'http://flutter-api.test/api/';

  Future<List<Category>> fetchCategories() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('${baseUrl}categories'),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
        },
      );

    List categories = jsonDecode(response.body);

    return categories.map((category) => Category.fromJson(category)).toList();
  }

  Future <Category> addCategory(String name) async {

    String uri = '${baseUrl}categories';

    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
        },
        body: jsonEncode({'name': name}));
        
        if(response.statusCode != 201){
          throw Exception('Error happened on create');
        }

    return Category.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }
  
  Future <Category> updateCategory(Category category) async {

    String uri = '${baseUrl}categories/${category.id}';

    http.Response response = await http.put(Uri.parse(uri),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
        },
        body: jsonEncode({'name': category.name}));
        
        if(response.statusCode != 200){
          throw Exception('Error happened on update');
        }

    return Category.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }

  Future<void> deleteCategory(id) async {

    String uri = '${baseUrl}categories/$id';    

    http.Response response = await http.delete(Uri.parse(uri),
    headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
        },
      );
    
 
    if(response.statusCode != 204){
          // // ignore: avoid_print 
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(response.statusCode);
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(response.body.toString());
      throw Exception('Error happened on delete');
    }

  }

  Future<List<Transaction>> fetchTransactions() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('${baseUrl}transactions'),
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
        HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
      },
    );

    List transactions = jsonDecode(response.body);

    return transactions.map((transaction) => Transaction.fromJson(transaction)).toList();
  }

  Future<Transaction> addTransaction(String amount, String category, String description, String date) async {
    String uri = '${baseUrl}transactions';

    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          'amount': amount,
          'category_id': category,
          'description': description,
          'transaction_date': date
        }));

    if (response.statusCode != 201) {
      throw Exception('Error happened on create');
    }

    return Transaction.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }

  Future<Transaction> updateTransaction(Transaction transaction) async {
    String uri = '${baseUrl}transactions/${transaction.id}';

    http.Response response = await http.put(Uri.parse(uri),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          'amount': transaction.amount,
          'category_id': transaction.categoryId,
          'description': transaction.description,
          'transaction_date': transaction.transactionDate
        }));

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Error happened on update');
    }

    return Transaction.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }

  Future<void> deleteTransaction(id) async {
    String uri = '${baseUrl}transactions/$id';
    http.Response response = await http.delete(
      Uri.parse(uri),
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
        HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode != 204) {
      throw Exception('Error happened on delete');
    }
  }

  Future<String> register(String name, String email, String password, String passwordConfirm, String deviceName) async {
    // ignore: prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings
    String uri = baseUrl + 'auth/register';
    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri),
      headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
        },
      body: jsonEncode({
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'password_confirmation': passwordConfirm,
        'device_name': deviceName
      })
    );
    if(response.statusCode == 422){
      Map<String, dynamic> body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      Map<String, dynamic> errors = body['errors'];
      String errorMessage = '';
      errors.forEach((key, value){
        value.forEach((element){
          errorMessage += element + '\n';
        });
      });

      throw Exception(errorMessage);
    }
    // if(response.statusCode == 422){
    //   throw Exception('Error happened on registration');
    // }

    return response.body;
  }

  Future<String> login(String email, String password, String deviceName) async {
    // ignore: prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings
    String uri = baseUrl + 'auth/login';
    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri),
      headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',          
        },
      body: jsonEncode({
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'device_name': deviceName
      })
    );
    if(response.statusCode == 422){
      Map<String, dynamic> body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      Map<String, dynamic> errors = body['errors'];
      String errorMessage = '';
      errors.forEach((key, value){
        value.forEach((element){
          errorMessage += element + '\n';
        });
      });

      throw Exception(errorMessage);
    }
    // if(response.statusCode == 422){
    //   throw Exception('Error happened on registration');
    // }

    return response.body;
  }
 

}
```